# Only one module can display

Tags: joomla-2.5

How can I when I click on a menu
Only one module can display

I do not want to set me on my
Because Joomla saves me when I'm
Selection error Catagoris

I just want when I click on the menu
Dedicated show news display module

Comment: I tried but it is hard to understand what you want to do/say. Do you want to have 1 specific different module for each menu item?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit hard to understand exactly what your asking, however it does seem like you want to extend the default functionality of modules. For this nonumbers advanced module manager is perfect.

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

It would take pages to go over all it can do, I would recommend installing it and seeing it in action. There is no harm in having it and even the free version has all the features you really need.

Also if what you need is to have a page where only one module shows, you can create a module with just {loadposition module-position} or {loadmodule ID} to load just that module into the page.

If I am missing the mark on what is being asked please let me know and I can adjust to suit.